# Can't find umbraco data storage

Tags: sql-server, database, umbraco, localdb

I have installed  Umbraco via WebMatrix, and entered `"server=(localdb)\v11.0;integrated security=true"` as a connection string. The site works fine, but I can't find the database that Umbraco have created. When I open the `(localdb)\v11.0`, it's not there.

I have tried searching whole system with `*.mdf`. but no luck. Where can the data be?

I am using umbraco 4.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. With no Database defined, SQL server uses the first or the default database in the list, which appears to `master` database. SSMS and such, don't display tables of system objects, so I found the tables by querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the database is in the user profile folder of the account that Umbraco is running under. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx) for more complete explanation. You may also want to look at [this other post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx) about why LocalDB by default puts the database file in the root of the user profile of the account it runs under.

Comment: It was the first place I've looked in.

Comment: What account is Umbraco running under?

Comment: It's IIS Express, so it must be my account.